# Worst first serve percentage in a match during a grand slam

Tags: trivia, tennis, statistics

Is there a record of who has had the worst first serve percentage during a singles match in a grand slam event? This question includes both men's and women's games.

Answer (score 2):

From various sources round the Web, but probably originally Associated Press content ([one example](http://amarillo.com/stories/012199/spo_LS0006.shtml#.WJR8ObNamV4)):

> Even the worst tennis hacker with the wackiest serve would find it tough to top **Anna Kournikova**'s **31** double faults at the Australian Open in a farce of a match that was so bad it was funny.
>
> It was one of most feeble and unintentionally comical matches of all time, and the packed crowd groaned and hooted, laughed and whistled through every excruciating moment of it.
>
> That **Kournikova** could win 1-6, 6-4, 10-8 against Japan's **Miho Saeki** after setting perhaps an all-time record for sloppy serving Thursday speaks volumes for the way both players performed. Between them they made 149 unforced errors with 21 breaks of service. Once in a while they actually came up with some pretty good shots from the baseline and the net.
>
> **Kournikova**, a popular 17-year-old Russian seeded No. 12, served for the match seven times, double faulted twice on match points, drilled an easy overhead into the net on one more, and played with all the consistency of a rank amateur. It wasn't as if **Kournikova** was going for big serves all the time — she had just three aces to zero for Saeki. She simply couldn't put the yellow ball in the green box.
>
> About 3,000 fans jamming Court 2 cheered her nevertheless, their sympathy stretched to the limit as the 2½-hour match wore on. When Saeki hit a backhand crosscourt wide to lose the match at last, the crowd roared in celebration and relief.
>
> **Kournikova**, who slugged 23 double faults in her first-round match, slumped in her chair and covered her face with a towel after shaking hands with Saeki, then obliged her adoring fans by signing autographs.
>
> Double fault records are not kept, but no one among even the oldest observers could recall a professional player who served worse in a match. There was, however, one **Gerald Patterson** of Australia, who served 29 double faults and 29 aces in capturing the five-set final of the Australian championships in 1927.

Comment: If you're going to quote large chunks verbatim from other sources, please put them in the appropriate block quote markup to make it clear that it's not your content - plagiarism is bad.

Comment: @Philip Kendall, I didn't know that stuff. I will take of that from next time. Thank you for your valuable advice.